# FAST corner detection implementation in MATLAB finding non-corner features

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to implement the FAST corner detection algorithm in Matlab, I am aware that there is already a pre-built version. I am not sure why my implementation seems to detect features that aren't even close to the edge or that are just bad.

```
readImage1 = imread('img1.png');
im1 = rgb2gray(readImage1);
img1 = medfilt2(im1);

rowStart = 0.1 * size(img1, 1);
rowStart = fix(rowStart);
rowEnd = 0.9 * size(img1, 1);
rowEnd = fix(rowEnd);

colStart = 0.1 * size(img1, 2);
colStart = fix(colStart);
colEnd = 0.9 * size(img1, 2);
colEnd = fix(colEnd);
```

Read my image, perform median blue. I only want feature detection to start a certain distance from the edges of the image.

```
array = [ ; ];

for c = colStart:colEnd
    for r = rowStart:rowEnd

        %get the intesity of the pixel
        intensity = img1(r, c);

        temp = [r,c];

        intensity1 = img1((r+3), c);
        intensity5 = img1(r+1, c+3);
        intensity9 = img1(r-3, c);
        intensity13 = img1(r+1, c-3);

        threshold = 70;

        count = IntensityCount(intensity1, intensity9, intensity5, intensity13, intensity, threshold);

        if count >= 3
              array = [array; temp];
        end
    end
end
```

Then, for each pixel, compare the intensity of the pixel with its 4 most important neighbors. If it is detected as a corner, save it into an Nx2 array.

After this, perform non-maximal suppression.

```
[rows, columns] = size(array);

discardArray = [ ; ];

for index = 2:rows
    currX = array(index);
    currY = array(index, 2);

    prevX = array(index - 1);
    prevY = array(index - 1, 2);

    if(adjacencyCheck(currX, currY, prevX, prevY))
        currScore = pixelScore(img1, currX, currY);
        prevScore = pixelScore(img1, prevX, prevY);

        if(currScore > prevScore)
            temp = [prevX, prevY];
            discardArray = [discardArray; temp];
        else
            temp = [currX, currY];
            discardArray = [discardArray; temp];
        end

    end
end

discardArray = unique(discardArray, 'rows');
finalArray = setdiff(array,discardArray, 'rows');
```

Then show the points on the image.

```
[rows, columns] = size(finalArray);

for index = 1:rows
   img1 = insertMarker(img1, [finalArray(index), finalArray(index,2)], 'x'); 
end

imshow(img1);
```

The functions used for intensity checks and non-maximal suppression.

```
function number = IntensityCount(int1, int9, int5, int13, origIntensity, thresh)

number = 0;

if abs(int1 - origIntensity) > thresh
    number = number + 1;
end

if abs(int9 - origIntensity) > thresh
    number = number + 1;
end

if abs(int5 - origIntensity) > thresh
    number = number + 1;
end

if abs(int13 - origIntensity) > thresh
    number = number + 1;
end

end

%Get the score by sum of absolute differences between the pixel and its neighbours.
function scoreNumber = pixelScore(img, r, c)

intOriginal = img(r,c);
intensity1 = img((r+3), c);
intensity3 = img(r+3, c-1);
intensity5 = img(r+1, c+3);
intensity7 = img(r-1, c+3);
intensity9 = img(r-3, c);
intensity11 = img(r-3, c-1);
intensity13 = img(r+1, c-3);
intensity15 = img(r-1, c-3);

scoreNumber = abs(intOriginal - intensity1) + abs(intOriginal - intensity3)+ abs(intOriginal - intensity5) + abs(intOriginal - intensity7) + abs(intOriginal - intensity9) + abs(intOriginal - intensity11) + abs(intOriginal - intensity13) + abs(intOriginal - intensity15); 
end

%Check pixel adjacency using Euclidean distance. 
function isAdjacent = adjacencyCheck(x1, y1, x2, y2)
xDist = x1 - x2;
yDist = y1 - y2;

dist = (xDist.^2 + yDist.^2).^0.5;

isAdjacent = dist <= 4;
end
```

[image: The feature points this algorithm detects]

Why is my algorithm detecting so many bad features?

Comment: @CrisLuengo insertMarker is a function in MatLab. https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/insertmarker.html

Comment: A few notes: `intensity5 = img1(r+1, c+3)`, why `+1`? `array = [array; temp];` requires a copy every time you append something, try pre-allocating the array (you can guess as to how many points you can possibly get, then crop the array at the end), or mark the points in a binary image instead of a list. `[finalArray(index), finalArray(index,2)]` is the same as `finalArray(index,:)`.

Comment: Im sure you know how FAST works, but incase you don't, I need to compare the pixel intensity against a certain number of pixels in a circle of radius 3px from the center. Tracing the pixel locations on paper, it seems like I need to recheck the locations. 
  
I'll look into marking the image onto a binary image, because I think I can then just use find() to looks for those pixels again. Switching those values around worked, I'm getting decent corners now. Thank you!

Comment: I was wondering about the `+1` because of symmetry. If you are sampling 4 points, I would sample `(r+3, c)`, (r, c+3)`, `(r-3, c)` and `(r, c-3)`. You use `r+1` twice, leading to a non-isotropic sampling of the four directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the unfortunate difficulties with MATLAB syntax, and which often causes confusion.

As you know, MATLAB indexes into matrices as `[row,column]`, which is natural in linear algebra and totally appropriate for matrices. But because MATLAB has expanded way beyond linear algebra, matrices are often used to store spatial data, in which `x` increases along the columns of the matrix, and `y` increases along the rows. Thus, a spatial location `[x,y]` should be reversed to find indices into the matrix: `[y,x]`.

The [`insertMarker`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/insertmarker.html) is one of the functions that takes a spatial location in the form of `[x,y]` rather than indices into the matrix. Thus, switching `[finalArray(index), finalArray(index,2)]` to `[finalArray(index,2), finalArray(index,1)]` should fix this issue.

Do note that `[finalArray(index,2), finalArray(index,1)]` can also be written as `finalArray(index,[2,1])`.